# Sound doesn't play the expected amount of times

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to accomplish playing a sound effect multiple times; first, it is triggered by the press of the button, and then it plays twice more after, in intervals intended to be two seconds after the last.

My current (relevant) HTML:

```
    <!-- AUDIO -->
    <audio id="ring_audio" autostart="false" src="http://www.freesound.org/data/previews/352/352300_2247456-lq.mp3"></audio>
    <audio id="ring_audio2" autostart="false" src="http://www.freesound.org/data/previews/352/352300_2247456-lq.mp3"></audio>
    <audio id="click_audio" autostart="false" src="http://www.freesound.org/data/previews/192/192273_3509815-lq.mp3"></audio>

    <div id="title_screen">
    <img src="http://data.whicdn.com/images/66375886/large.gif">
    <h1>Untitled.</h1>
    <h2>a short adventure game</h2>
    <button id="start" type="button" onclick="playClick(); fade_title(); playRing_Delay(); playRing_Stop();">Begin</button>
    </div>
```

And my current javascript:

```
function playClick() {
    var audio = document.getElementById("click_audio");
    audio.currentTime = 0.3;
    audio.play();
}
function fade_title() {
    var titlescreen = document.getElementById("title_screen");
    titlescreen.style.display = "none";
}
function playRing_Delay() {
    setTimeout(function playRing() {
        var audio = document.getElementById("ring_audio");
        audio.play();
    }, 5000);
    setTimeout(function playRing() {
        var audio = document.getElementById("ring_audio");
        audio.play();
    }, 7000);
}
function playRing_Stop() {
    setTimeout (function playRing() {
        var audio = document.getElementById("ring_audio2");
        audio.play();
    }, 9000);
}
```

**Originally**, I attempted to tackle this through use of a for loop and keep it contained just to one function:

```
function playRing_Delay() {
    setTimeout(function playRing() {
        var audio = document.getElementById("ring_audio");
        for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            if i < 3 { //the first two times
                audio.play(); //plays audio as normal
            }
            else { //the last time it plays
                audio.play();
                setTimeout(function stopRing() {
                    audio.pause();
                }, 500) //stops audio after half a second
            }
        }
    }, 5000);
}
```

Which, sadly, did not work, so then I attempted to repeat the first bit three times, simply increasing the number of waiting milliseconds so they'd follow in proper succession; I'm not going to paste it because essentially I just put playRing_Stop()'s contents inside of playRing_Delay()'s.

Additionally, I noticed that when I shifted the final ring's wait period (from 9000ms > 2000ms), it played, followed by the one set to 5000ms (as expected), and the second one (7000ms) didn't.

Could someone provide a solution for this - or at the very least explain to me why it happens?

*Note*: I purposely left out the early stopping point to the third ring in the other methods after my for loop method failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because the `#ring_audio` file is 3 seconds long, and you are trying to replay it after 2 seconds. So it is still playing when you issue the 2nd `play` command to it.

You should set its `currentTime` to 0 if you want to restart it before finishing (*or wait the full 3 seconds before re-running `play` on it*)

```
function playRing_Delay() {
    setTimeout(function playRing() {
        var audio = document.getElementById("ring_audio");
        audio.play();
    }, 5000);
    setTimeout(function playRing() {
        var audio = document.getElementById("ring_audio");
        audio.currentTime = 0;
        audio.play();
    }, 7000);
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Any idea why it still played the second time and just not the third?

Comment: @paypercrane it was the second repetition that was being skipped, due to the problem I mention in the answer.

Comment: My reading comprehension evidently needs some work. Thanks again!